# How should I use the word “written” in sentences below?

Tags: passive-voice

I always use the “written“ in passive voice as is the case with sentences:

> “Wash me“ was written on this car.

But I wonder if the way of using ”written” in sentence below is correct:

> It was written “wash me“ on the car.

I think second sentence seem ungrammatical. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please be careful with punctuation and spelling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

“Wash me“ was written on this car. It was very funny. That is correct.

It was written “wash me“ on the car.  **That is not correct.**

Please note: "It" is the pronoun that stands for  "wash me". See the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> ✘ It was written “ wash me “ on the car.

You are correct that the sentence is ungrammatical.

---

However, you could turn it into the equivalent of reported speech (*reported writing* if I'm going to coin a phrase) by removing the quote:

> It was written (on the car) *that the car be washed*.

---

Note that, in theory, it's only an assumption that *me* in *wash me* is referring to the car. If you don't want to make that assumption, you could be more ambiguous:

> It was written (on the car) *that somebody or something be washed*.

Comment: You mean *un*-grammatical?